# Import crypto price feed into google sheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Anyone know how to do this?  Just looking to pull in price data for certain cryptos into google sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

*You can use the built-in funcion [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en).*

### Examples

- Bitcoin: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:BTCUSD")` : $54,348.20
- Etherum: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:ETHUSD")`: $2,614.33
- Litecoin: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:LTCUSD")`: $254.00
- Euro: `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD")` : $1.21

### More features

I recommend you to take a look to the documentation of the function, as it has different features that can be helpful to you. For example, you can creates a chart inside a cell to display the currency exchange trend in a specific time range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Binance and this function

```
function pricePair(currencyPair) {    
  var url = 'https://api3.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=' + currencyPair;
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = reponse.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data.price;  
}
```

with parameter currencyPair as BTCUSDT, ETHUSDT, DOGEUSDT, ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this.  I copied that whole function and pasted it into a cell.  Then I changed currencyPair with ETHUSDT in both instances.  But its returning an error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Bruno, you have to get authorizations ... execute the function inside the script editor, you will have an error bbut google will ask your authorization (clic advanced and go to the last step).

Comment: When I go to tools->script editor, it opens a blank page in another tab.

Comment: Does that help you ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGuR2ju5JqhptW4xOeUl_vk7Iqk-ExS-UMvuLnBcsHs/copy feel free to ask me any more help.

Comment: @Mike, I used your code but got error `Request failed for https://api3.binance.com returned code 403`.  Yet it works for ADAUSDT on your spreadsheet just fine!  Google did not ask for any extra authorisations, any suggestions please?

Comment: If you receive an HTTP 403 error, it indicates that you have broken a rule. Most often, this is an excessive number of requests made over a period of 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers

Google Finance is quite limited, with only a few of the biggest coins being tracked.

In alternative, use a proper API which gives you an easy to use endpoint, example:

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")`